# mysql limit minimum not being set

Tags: php, mysql, limit

well this should be easy for someone---

I am trying to select specific rows in a database

```
SELECT * FROM customers LIMIT 10,20
```

but it always returns 20 rows

what is going on, and why does the minimum not have any value?

Comment: SELECT * FROM customer LIMIT 19,20  --- this returns 14 rows

Comment: That means you have 33 customers?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: Before going to stackoverflow and asking a question at least consult the documentation please. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: thanks Daniel for the help? I get theres documentation - it wasn't clear to me and I needed some help, others helped me out and I was able to solve the issue - you have zero value here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
LIMIT X, Y
```

means that you get `Y` results starting from number `X+1`.

So if you want values from 11 to 20 you need to use:

```
LIMIT 10, 10
```

Comment: and it is shown that I have been coding for 15 hours... I read the doc 10 times, and looked at their demo but couldn't get it.... Thanks! Will accept after time limit

Comment: Specifically X is the number of rows to skip and Y is the number of rows to return after skipping X rows.

Comment: Thanks @DanielWilliams you are right. I update my answer with this specification.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to do `limit 10` or `lmit 0, 10` for 10 results

Answer (score 1):

The second number of the `LIMIT` clause is the number of rows to be returned, not the last index. if you only want 10 rows, replace `20` by `10` in your query limit clause.

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers
LIMIT 10, 10
```

Answer (score 1):

`Limit` with two arguments `(x,y)` means you get rows from `x+1 to y`. From the MySQL Manual:

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned
>   by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments,
>   which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using
>   prepared statements).
>
> With two arguments, **the first argument specifies the offset of the
>   first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of
>   rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1)**:

`SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;`

> Retrieve rows 6-15 To retrieve all
>   rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result set, you can
>   use some large number for the second parameter.
>
> This statement
>   retrieves all rows from the 96th row to the last:

`SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615;`

> With one argument,
>   the value specifies the number of rows to return from the beginning of
>   the result set:

`SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5;`

> Retrieve first 5 rows In other words,
>   LIMIT row_count is equivalent to LIMIT 0, row_count.